# Changing light fixture and wanting to know colour codings for cables

Tags: wiring

Am about to change an old wall light fitting with a new one.  The cable coming out of wall is 3 cables, red, brown and green.  All i have read state that red and brown are both live and green is Earth.  Does that mean I donthave a neutral as my light fixture is asking for a L, N and earth.

Comment: Can you post photos of what's up?

Comment: Where do you live?  This is important for electrical questions.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t rely on colors, use a multimeter and check which is what.

While it may have started out ok someone else could have played in the past... So be safe and check. I only trust wiring I have done...

Comment: The only time the power should be on is when you're checking voltages. You should have the breaker controlling the circuit you're working on "OFF" all the rest of the time. Good luck.